# Refer to ran Keras model.fit or model.predict without assigning it to a variable

Tags: python, keras, plot, model, output

I don't seem to grasp how I can use the output of the model.fit to direct it into the analization part without beforehandedly assigning the model.fit to a variable (most of the time I see 'history' as variable reference). I forgot to do so (assign it to a variable), and don't want to re-run the model fit just to assign it to a variable; model fit takes up to 30 minutes. How can I grasp the output of the model.fit or refer to it in plotting evaluation metrics? Sorry for vague explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IPython based environment (which is likely if you are doing ML stuff), the output of every cell is stored in a dictionary called `Out` with an integer correspondent to the order of execution of that cell as key.

So, if you ran `model.fit(...` as the **last command** in a cell, and let's say in the order of execution is 13 (this number would normally appear in the left side of the cell), you can reference it as `Out[13]`.